# what is the relationship about reactive-ipc, reactive stream io, reactive stream net and reactivesocket

Tags: rx-java, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I found many repos in Github about reactive stream,seems there are similar.

However, many repos are not updated several months.

I want to know the relationship about them and i can focus on the latest repos.

reactive-ipc:https://github.com/reactive-ipc/reactive-ipc-jvm

reactive-streams-net:https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-net-jvm

reactivesocket:https://github.com/ReactiveSocket/reactivesocket-java.git

Comment: Why don't you ask their maintainers?

Answer (score 2):

They all were established to explore ideas about streaming in or out of a Java process by some means, via inter-process communication or via networking. The first two seem to be stagnating and the latest appears to be more active recently.